# If catalog flat product is enabled topsellers collection no image,name,price!

Tags: product-collection

Hi i need to enable catalog flat product to boost magento but i have big problem with magento collection. If $visibility is enabled it will crash with `4 Unknown column 'e.visibility' in 'where clause'` , if i remove it will load the collection but without image,price,name. 
 i manage to include name and price in app/core/core.../Collection.php but still i don't know how to load the image.
Maybe this is the wrong way but i hoped it will work, i was wrong.
even 2,3 free extensions that i have used will not work on if collection is from reports.
any help?

Comment: To add attributes to the `catalog_product_flat` tables, you need to set them "used in product listing" yes.

Answer (score 2):

Don't edit `app/core/core.../Collection.php` never! To add some attribute to flat table, you should configure this attribute. Read this [What are the differences between EAV and Flat catalogs?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9088/what-are-the-differences-between-eav-and-flat-catalogs)

Comment: Attribute price is in "product listing" but still not displaying.any info?also about the image?