# addAttributeToSort() not working with flat product data

Tags: flat-catalog

We have a bit of code that looks like this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('sellbydate');
$products->addAttributeToSort('sellbydate','ASC');
```

This has been working fine, but after enabling flat product data the items are no longer sorted.  I have reindexed but there is no change.

Should I be using a different function?

Comment: Could you show the query that is executed by adding the following debug line `var_dump((string)$products->getSelect());` below your code?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9088/what-are-the-differences-between-eav-and-flat-catalogs

Answer (score 3):

The function is correct and checks to see if the catalog is in flat mode. So do not worry about that. Make sure that your attribute is set correctly so that there is a column for it on the flat table.

I think setting `used_in_product_listing` to yes via a set-up script or via the admin, then preform a reindex should solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using flat tables you should use setOrder()/addOrder() instead of addAttributeToSort().
Take a look here : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately I can't find a solution from that link.  I have tried addSort/setSort and also unshiftSort and none of them change anything.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352128/magento-non-eav-collection-sort-order ( MagePsycho )